# API with Parameters in Power BI

Tags: api, microsoft-powerbi

New to Power BI but hoping someone can point me in the right direction....

I have a API that I use to pull data from an ERP databoard via Postman but it holds various params to make it work see below:

API call is a POST:

```
url/api/json/reply/DataboardDataRequest
```

Headers used are:

[header examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFvwQ.png)

I also have to set some criteria like the number of the ERP databoard via the body of the API as below:

```
{"DataboardId":10043,"Parameters":{"1":"105","5":"0","10":"2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z","11":"2019-02-28T00:00:00.000Z","20":"0"}}
```

This works fine and pulls back all the info i need via postman but i would like to make this a direct link via Power BI.

Can anyone help in how i can recreate this call via the PBI interface?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Get Data / Web and then choose the Advanced option.  This opens features like adding Header values and using Query Parameters as input.